# Rendering Sprites in Three.js over 3D Object and also behind without clipping

Tags: three.js, rendering

I need a way to render a sprite always over top of a 3DObject, but it also must disappear behind it when the camera is rotated.

I first tried disabling the depth-buffer write but this will always render the Sprite in front.

Is there a way to hide it when its behind, but prevent clipping with the Object?

Edit 1:

The Problem is not exactly about z-fighting because the depthbuffer values of the sprite and the object are not equal.
The Sprite is a Billboard, so it will always face the camera, but it clips with the object, when rotating the camera.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You should be able to mitigate the issue by configuring a polygon offset. Try it with `polygonOffset: true, polygonOffsetFactor: - 4`.

Comment: I will look into this. thank you

Comment: @Mugen87 This only works for z-fighting, what is not the case here. My depthbuffer Values are different.